# What $n$-links can be represented as closed pure braids?

Tags: knot-theory, braid-groups

The [Alexander's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_theorem) states that every link can be represented as a closed braid. How about if only the pure braid are allowed to be used in the representation? Obviously the closure of every pure $n-$braid is an $n-$link. But the question is:

What $n$-links can be represented as closed pure braids?

One answer would be "if and only if the $n$-link has [braid index](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BraidIndex.html) $n$". But how can one characterise $n-$links with braid index $x$?

Comment: The closure of any pure braid is a link of unlinks as there are no self-crossings. Links of unlinks like the Whitehead link which have a self-crossing in any projection (a crossing between a component and itself) for similar reasons. The easiest examples of these things are the torus links $T(n,kn)$ but I don't think that these should be representative. I don't know any reason why the closure of pure braids should have some simple inherently different characterization. Surely recognizing such a thing from a random diagram would be hard.

Comment: Thank you so much @PVAL-inactive for your comment! Is it true that not every link of unlinks can be represented as the closure of some pure braids?

Comment: The only 2-component links will be $T(2,2n)$. This is pretty easy to see.

Comment: Sure. How about links with more than $2$ components? @PVAL-inactive